# Location of Checkout template

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am unable to track the location of checkout template.
When I try to find the location as mentioned in one of your questions I am unable to find it. I just get the location mentioned below

```
woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the location of the Checkout Template in woocommerce directory at

```
plugins\woocommerce\templates\checkout\form-checkout.php
```

from where different woo commerce hooks exist which triggers different HTML on the check out page.